# How to install compass-normalize?

Tags: ruby, nodejs, npm

When compilation gulp I get the following error:

```
LoadError on line ["55"] of /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass-normalize Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I'm using the below version of ruby and compass:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ compass -v
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2018 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
```

How to install compass-normalize in ubuntu?

Comment: guys i need help!

Comment: Which command did you execute which cause the error?

Comment: @Yaron , command gulp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [compass-normalize git hub](https://github.com/ksmandersen/compass-normalize)

> **Installation**
>
> It is highly encouraged to install from the [RubyGems build](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass-normalize) which
> can be found [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass-normalize).
>
> From the command line:
>
> ```
> $ gem install compass-normalize
> ```
>
> You can also install the gem from your local clone:
>
> ```
> $ git clone git://github.com/ksmandersen/compass-normalize.git
> $ rake build
> $ rake install
> ```
>
> **Usage**
>
> When creating a new project with compass:
>
> ```
> $ compass create <my_project> -r compass-normalize --using compass-normalize
> ```
>
> If using an existing project, edit your config.rb and add this line:
>
> ```
> require 'compass-normalize'
> ```
>
> To use the normalize plugin, just import and include normalize:
>
> ```
> @import "normalize";
> ```

---

> Note: SO Q&A discussion [sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations)
>
> 1. You can also install gems in your local environment (without sudo) with
>
>    gem install --user-install
> 2. I recommend you install [RVM](https://rvm.io/) and start a happy life with portable gem homes and different version of Ruby all living under one roof.

---

Regarding the second question mentioned in the comments below regarding `DEPRECATION WARNING`:

There is a known issue in `compass` which was mentioned [here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/pull/2088)

A branch with fix was published [here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/pull/2088), updating `compass` with the fix can be done using:

```
git 'https://github.com/ably-forks/compass', branch: 'sass-deprecation-warning-fix' do
  gem 'compass-core'
end
```

Similar issue was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905367/deprecation-warning-on-ruby-with-compass)

Comment: gem install compass-normalize

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.`

Comment: Your gem command tries to install it as `root` you can execute the `gem` command as `root` using `sudo` however other methods are recommended - Please review this [SO-Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations) how to install gem without using `sudo`

Comment: i write sudo gem install compass-normalize. Gulp working but, i have new problem after command gulp.

Comment: `DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of /usr/share/compass/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#{$experimental-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.`

Comment: and

`[12:39:31] DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of /usr/share/compass/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6} "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7} "$ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
`

Comment: accepting, but my question to the end there is no answer

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович - updated my answer with additional info

Comment: Good luck!Im glad to see you